# Create a product base table by date

Tags: oracle

I want to create a query that returns number of active products by colander date. I don’t have calendar dim table in database.

Current table

```
Product_name|prod_id|start_date|end_date
P1|1234|02/01/2020|30/05/2020
P1|2345|02/01/2020|31/12/9999
P1|3456|03/01/2020|31/12/9999
```

Expected Result

```
Calander_date|product_name|active_base

01/01/2020|P1|0
02/01/2020|P1|2
03/01/2020|P1|3
01/06/2020|P1|2
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Abhishek. What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own calendar, then - either in the database, as a "real" table (row generator technique helps here), or as a CTE (as I did in the following example):

```
SQL> with
  2  test (product_name, prod_id, start_date, end_date) as
  3    -- you have that table; don't type that
  4    (select 'P1', 1234, date '2020-01-02', date '2020-05-30' from dual union all
  5     select 'P1', 2345, date '2020-01-02', date '9999-12-31' from dual union all
  6     select 'P1', 3456, date '2020-01-03', date '9999-12-31' from dual
  7    ),
  8  calendar (datum) as
  9    -- create your own calendar table
 10    (select date '2020-01-01' + level - 1
 11     from dual
 12     connect by level <= 10000   --> number of days you want in calendar
 13    )
 14  -- final query - join!
 15  select c.datum,
 16    t.product_name,
 17    count(*) active_base
 18  from calendar c join test t on c.datum between t.start_date and t.end_date
 19  group by c.datum, t.product_name
 20  order by c.datum;

DATUM      PR ACTIVE_BASE
---------- -- -----------
02/01/2020 P1           2
03/01/2020 P1           3
04/01/2020 P1           3
05/01/2020 P1           3
06/01/2020 P1           3
<snip>
28/05/2020 P1           3
29/05/2020 P1           3
30/05/2020 P1           3
31/05/2020 P1           2
01/06/2020 P1           2
02/06/2020 P1           2
<snip>
```